# psycopg2 for python3 on Centos 7

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, centos, centos7

Has anyone installed `psycopg2` for **python 3** on **Centos 7**?  I'm sure it's possible, but when I run:

`pip install psycopg2`

I get:

*Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyscopg2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyscopg2*

Answer (score 2):

You have misspelled the name of the library.  The correct name is `psycopg2`

Comment: @AronYsidoro are you still receiving the same error when you try to install it with the correct speling?

Comment: I got it resolved.  I had compiled python 3.3, and had a bad path, so my python 3.3 virtualenv wasn't working correctly.  When I rebuild python 3, then everything works fine.